# Query Optimization - CTE Is Slow With OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, postgresql-9.3

I am running the below query that utilizes a `CTE` - the full recordset is roughly 10K records.  When I do a `Select Top 1000` the query takes roughly 45 seconds to return the results.  I am querying a `postgresql` database from `sql server 2008`

Is there a quicker way of writing this query?

```
Select [Employee Name] = employeename,[Customer Number] = Customernumber
,AVG(quantityordered) As AverageQty,AVG(Price) As AveragePrice
,[Sale Date] = CAST(Saledate As Date)
FROM OPENQUERY(192.155.10.22,'with MaxNumber as
                      (   
                        select max(cc2) as "MCN"   
                        ,Customernumber    
                        from employeeinfo    
                        group by Customernumber
                      )
                      Select
                      c1.employeename,c1.Customernumber
                      ,c1.Saledate,ep.saledc1cription
                      ,eq.quantityordered,eq.price
                      FROM MaxNumber c2
                      INNER JOIN Customer c1
                      ON c2.Customernumber=c1.Customernumber
                      AND COALESCE(c2."MCN",0)=COALESCE(c1.cc2,0)
                      INNER JOIN orderpart ep
                      ON ep.Customer = c1.Customerid
                      INNER JOIN orderquantity eq
                      ON eq.employeename = ep.employeename
                      INNER JOIN employee cm
                      ON c1.employee = cm.employee')
WHERE CAST(Saledate As Date) >= '01/01/2017'
GROUP BY customername, Customernumber, Saledate
```

**EDIT**
There are no indexes on the tables, and I am unable to modify them to add any.  And this is the execution plan
[image: Query Execution Plan]

Comment: I think you've asked enough of these query tuning questions to know we need more information than this. Query plan, indexes, etc.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - see edit.

Comment: Please add an actual execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ . Images require us to guess

Comment: Try putting the where clause inside the OPENQUERY statement.  Linked Servers have almost no optimization and it might be pulling back the entire recordset from your linked server and then filtering it down.

Comment: Is there a reason your where clause does filtering locally instead of in the remote query? Not being able to change indexes is going to hamper a lot of options.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik -> I can move it inside of the `openquery` - I understand not being able to add indexes hampers, just was not sure if there was a possibility of speeding things up any other way.

Comment: Adding the where clause inside of the `openquery` reduced return time from 45 seconds to 30 - so that has helped already!

Comment: The coalesce in that join condition may also cause some issues. I'm willing to bet that's the filter in your plan. Have you experimented with dumping the results to a temp table and aggregating from there?

Comment: I have not experimented with a temp table, as I need to be able to directly query.  I added the Coalesce() as sometimes the CTE() would return a null value and w/o the COALESCE() results would be skewed.

Comment: Why is the COALESCE for? Are both columns nullable?

Comment: I wonder why you haven't written the whole query inside the OPENQUERY.

Comment: There is a mismatch: the openquery has `employeename` but the external query has `group by customername`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I haven't used OPENQUERY, I'll add some - more or less common sense - notes:

- You are not doing any joins between the remote (Postgres) server tables and the SQL Server ones. I suggest you move the whole query inside the Openquery call.
- The `COALESCE()` suggests that the 2 columns are nullable? Are they?
  If not, remove the `COALESCE()` calls which prohibit the use of indexes. If they are nullable, you can try to modify the predicate to something like (if they can be 0, it'd have to be more complex):

  ```
  AND ( c2."MCN" = c1.cc2  OR  c2."MCN" IS NULL AND c1.cc2 IS NULL )
  ```
- The `CAST(Saledate As Date) >= '01/01/2017'` looks like a killer, too. There is no reason to use `CAST`. The expression can be written as (the cast may not be needed at all in Postgres, depending on the column type):

  ```
  Saledate >= CAST('2017-01-01' AS date)
  ```
- After pushing the whole query to the linked server, there is no reason to have the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` in the external query. You can collapse the query into one level.
- After the rewrite, and if it is still slow, check the execution plan in the remote server. Besides indexes, examine the plan regarding the CTE. CTEs in Postgres are optimization fences, and their use restricts the optimizer into certain options - which may be good or bad for efficiency - depending on too many variables.

---

The query, in Postgres syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(192.155.10.22, '
    WITH MaxNumber AS
      (   
        SELECT 
            MAX(cc2) AS "MCN"   
            Customernumber    
        FROM employeeinfo    
        GROUP BY Customernumber
      )
    SELECT 
        c1.employeename           AS "Employee Name",
        c1.Customernumber         AS "Customer Number",
        AVG(eq.quantityordered)   AS "AverageQty",
        AVG(eq.price)             AS "AveragePrice",
        CAST(c1.Saledate AS Date) AS "Sale Date"
    FROM
        MaxNumber c2
      INNER JOIN Customer c1
        ON  c2.Customernumber = c1.Customernumber
        AND COALESCE(c2."MCN", 0) = COALESCE(c1.cc2, 0)
      INNER JOIN orderpart ep
        ON  ep.Customer = c1.Customerid
      INNER JOIN orderquantity eq
        ON  eq.employeename = ep.employeename
      INNER JOIN employee cm
        ON  c1.employee = cm.employee
    WHERE 
        Saledate >= CAST('2017-01-01' AS date)
    GROUP BY 
        c1.customername, 
        c1.Customernumber, 
        CAST(c1.Saledate AS date)
')
```

(will still need fixing, there is a mismatch between the openquery which has `select employeename` and the external query which has `group by customername`)